# jQuery CSS Positioning onhover of div-elements (Cross Browser Issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create an interface using jQuery but having some difficulty making it work on different browsers although, what I am linking now should work on most of the Windows browsers.

See here: http://122.173.254.198/picasa_hover_experiment.htm

(Please note the problem part is programmed minimal and solution expected on same)

The problem is with images 3 and 8 which I want to focus on mouseover and show in between as other images. It fails to work on either Opera or IE 6 as I am testing. Would somebody provide me a cross-browser and working solution to it?

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome either

Comment: @Alastair Did u see...images moving to center and resizing on hover action.. except others on Chrome?

Comment: Stop adding your signature to your question. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your jQuery to 1.4.2...

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @Anvi: How do you know? I'm trying to narrow down the issues with your code. Having an old version of jQuery might mean bugs in the code your trying to leverage.